# What is the hollow in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage

She dressed in a severe black dress that revealed the soup-sized hollow at the base of her long neck.

Above sentence, What is the hollow? Is this a hollow of the dress or a hollow (caved-in shape) in the skin of the neck?

Comment: Please give source of the quote.  "soup-sized"  is odd for me, since soup doesn't have a particular size (a soup bowl is a typical size, a soup spoon has typical size  etc')

Comment: Ah, I've found it *The nightingale* by Kristin Hannah - as suspected you've miscopied it.  Please be **very** careful not to get any words wrong when you quote.

Comment: To clarify, the book said "soup spoon-sized hollow". Not a can of Campbell's..

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *soup-sized hollow* refers to a hollow in the bone structure of the lady.

*revealed* clarifies it further.  Something that is revealed in this context must be referring to a part of the body, rather than a part of the dress.

Comment: In anatomy (and not common speech, but this might help the OP find a picture) this is the suprasternal notch see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suprasternal_notch

Comment: Thank you so much.